# FlurryAgent:Agent cache file doesn't exist while implementing Flurry analytics in android

Tags: android, flurry

I am implementing flurry in application,and i have written code following code,

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
    Log.i(Tag,"onStart");   
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this,Keys.Flurry_Key);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.INFO);
    FlurryAgent.onEvent("Mainscreen");
    FlurryAgent.logEvent("user is on home screen");
    }

@Override
protected void onStop()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    }
```

but after executing the code above i am getting the log as,

```
05-13 11:52:10.954: I/FlurryAgent(371): Agent cache file doesn't exist.
05-13 11:52:10.954: I/FlurryAgent(371): Generated id
```

what does it mean? does it mean that flurry is not integrated well in my app?
if not how can i solve it?

Note:i have included the required permissions in manifest.
     i am running project in Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please use the new Flurry SDK v3.2.0, and retry? If the issue persists, please send over a mail to support@flurry.com along with your API key.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Comment: :thanks for your reply,flurry is integrated well in my app(though it shows strange log messages).But i want to know what above log message mean?